# Colouring a graph in my program and adding values

Tags: c#, charts

I want to ask if its possible to color the negative values of the chart a different color from the positive ones. Also how can i enter marks on the values like tagg the values at 1,2,3..10 etc! The values range from -300000 up to 700000

The chart is in C# and i have a button that executes the following:

```
decimal[] numbers = new decimal[20];

for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) 
{  
    numbers[i] = Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1[7, i].Value);  
    chart1.Series["Loan_Balance"].Points.AddXY(i+1, numbers[i]); } 
    chart1.Series["Loan_Balance"].Color = Color.Blue; 
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Interval = 50000;
    chart1.Series["Loan_Balance"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Range;
}
```

Also i wanted to ask, why when i enter the values straight from the database (datagridview). For example in the for loop, instead of creating an array and convert the values from the datagridview to decimal, to plot them straight in like:

```
chart1.Series["Loan_Balance"].Points.AddXY(i, dataGridView2[i, 0].Value);
```

the `chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Interval = 50000;`
behaves strangely, most of the times it doesn't work at all

The coloring problem is much more important if you could help me i would truly appreciate it.

Thanking you in advance
Best Regards
George Georgiou

Comment: What Charting library are you using?

Comment: the charts from the toolbox. I had to add also using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be creating the points directly rather than using `AddXY`. This gives you full control over the point including it's color. So, rather than:

```
chart1.Series["Loan_Balance"].Points.AddXY(i+1, numbers[i]);
```

Use:

```
var point = new DataPoint(i+1, numbers[i]);
point.Color = numbers[i] < 0 ? Color.Red : Color.Black; // or whatever logic
point.Label = numbers[i].ToString();                    // and so on
chart1.Series["Loan_Balance"].Points.Add(point);
```

You can see what other properties are available on the `DataPoint` here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.datapoint.aspx

Comment: Thx very much for your help, but since i have the values of the datapoints, i was wondering whether i can add 1 extra datapoint where my line crosses the x axis. The value of Y will be certainly 0 but the value of X is unknown. Is there a function that gives the point where a line crosses an axis? Thank you very much